# CodeShip supports iOS Project

Tags: ios, codeship

Does CodeShip Supports iOS projects. I have a GitHub Project and I have enabled the integration with CodeShip. I have test cases written using XCTest Framework. I don't know how to configure CodeShip to execute the test case for successful build. Anyone knows whether we can integrate iOS project with CodeShip.

Answer (score 2):

CodeShip doesn't support iOS projects, because they don't have macOS servers/virtual machines, and you can only use Xcode and build iOS apps on macOS.

Check out https://www.bitrise.io/ for macOS builds.

Comment: Yeah, since CodeShip supports docker. Any idea on how to set up the Docker to build the iOS Apps.

Comment: @New16 docker can't run any other guest, and can't run on anything else, only Linux. When you run it on Mac/Windows it creates a Linux VM in the background, that's why you can run the Linux docker containers.

Comment: To be precise Docker now has a Windows Server version, which can run Windows guests, but for that it has to run on Windows, similar to the Linux one (because docker is built to use kernel/OS sharing, instead of creating an actual full virtual machine - it can only run containers with same OS/kernel as the host). There's absolutely no news/plans AFAIK to make it possible to run macOS guests in docker, and even if they would do that, you could only run that on macOS servers.

Comment: https://github.com/jkingyens/docker4xcode. This is what I got as I went through the docker for iOS. I am newbie in docker so I am still confused about it.

Comment: Check the requirements, the first one is osx (host)